# Is there such a thing as posting too much?

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions

Is there such a thing as posting too much for either questions or answers that are generally good quality, on Stack Overflow and Meta?

I myself have become a Meta hound recently and am doing lots on the Meta site, and am wondering, is it ever TOO much? And is the 'too much' simply a construct by the community, or will the system itself ever stop you from putting up questions or answers? This is knowing already that the system may stop you if you get downvoted in a certain way that the system detects it. Is it ever considered *too much* regardless of voting?

Comment: Quantify what you mean.  Do you mean you've got an overly verbose *answer* or *question*, or are you just answering every thing you see?  Does this apply to the main site or Meta or both?

Comment: @Makoto I mean generally good content being posted, answer or question. And applying to both sites.

Comment: I'm unclear why an overabundance of good content being posted by someone would be a negative thing...

Comment: Assuming [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) is still accurate, there is a limit on how many questions you can ask per day and per 30 days. There doesn't appear to be a limit on how many you can answer.

Comment: @BSMP This helps a lot, never saw this but clarifies everything. You could put that into an answer if you wanted.

Comment: No he can't. He has already reach the good answer's limit...

Comment: @TGrif Ha ha ha...

Comment: post as much as possible, delete everything that gets at least 1 downvote. easy reps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing as posting too much good content. While there are two rate limits for users with <125 reputation (3 minutes between posting answers, 40 between asking questions), these mostly exist to prevent spammers and make sure new users are putting enough thought into what they post. That's definitely not saying you don't need to put time and effort into what you post after you reach 125 rep; it's just that, at that point, you're trusted enough to post more often. Once you reach 125 reputation, the system will not rate limit you if what you post is frequently well-received.

If you've got something good to contribute, please do so. You're welcome to post as often as you want, *as long as you've put in enough time and effort to make your question or answer good*.

Comment: There is also max 200rep for upvoted answers per day.